# <form action="mailto: doesnt work in https page

Tags: html

mailto works in href but doesnt work in a form in a https page,

(I don't want to use PHP or any other language to send emails)

Comment: Are you visiting HTTP side and try to load HTTPS content? Maybe you redirect to `http://` instead of `https://`?

Comment: So index.html is served via https and contact.html is not? Then that's the problem.

Comment: no, both are served https://

Comment: @Justinas no i am not redirecting to http, contact.html works with https but the form doesnt work